# IOS > Open URL in Safari with POST

Tags: ios, url, paypal, safari, http-post

I'd like to launch a URL in Safari from UIView sending POST datas. This would allow me to load my Paypal page.

Normally, in HTML we have to do this :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="text-align:center;" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="submit" value="Faire un don" id="donpaypal">
</form>
```

I know that I can open a new URL with this few lines :

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http:://I.have.a.beautifull.website.com"]];
```

Is there a mean to specify POST datas OR would you have a mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to implement your custom browser using a UIWebView.
A UIWebView can load a NSURLRequest. 
Have a look at the following code

```
NSString *post = @"yourPostInformation";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];    
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Just to let you know how i did :

    NSString *post = @"cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"]];    
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: <!> Apps using this code will be rejected by apple...They prefer you to use in-app purchase... Paypal not allowed

Comment: How to send to Safari not on UIWebView?