# Using openScheme with POST

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that need to switch to Safari and open a link using a POST command. Since iOS 10 we are supposed to use 'openScheme', but where do a specify http method POST?

This is where I am so far;

```
- (void)openScheme:(NSString *)scheme
           options:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:scheme];
    [application openURL:URL options:options completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Opened %@",scheme);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding `URLSchemes`.

Below is the steps.

(i)  Open your `info` tab in targets.

(ii) At the below, you will find `URL Types` option.

(iii)Fill data as shown in below image.[image]

(iv) Now, open your Safari browser in iPhone/iPad, type `YourApp://` and enter. This should open your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not quite. The question I had was where to specify POST as being the method. At the moment I only send a GET.

Comment: Please take a look at this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500000/ios-open-url-in-safari-with-post
You are asking is not supported in openURL schemes.